# Confusing semantics on Python module system

Tags: python, module, semantics

Is it wrong to refer to Python modules and packages as "libraries" ? Is there a technical differense ? Python documentation never mentions the word "library" in the packages or modules entry, but always refers to Pythons' built-in code as "library".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's in a name? But as we are at it: 'library' is no technical/syntactical term in python and there is no <strike>organisational structure that would you call a python library.</strike> officially specified or mandatory way how you would organize your files and directories in your repository in order to call your project/package/module a library (while *package* is basically a directory with a `__init__.py` and a `module` is a `*.py` file.)

But that term is widely used for modules and packages which provide a collection of features, functions, classes and so on for other python projects and applications. You would call them a library as they are not intended to be a stand-alone application.

E.g. gentoo's portage is a python application while urllib is a library. There are python packages where this not so clear, like nosetests - I implement some of their classes and methods as if it is a library but then I call nosetests from the command line as if it is a stand-alone application.

As @StefanPochmann pointed out, there is a thing called 'The Python Standard Library'.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Sorry, wrong term. See my edit, I hope I made myself clear now.

Comment: Yeah, I think now it's ok :)